How to create a Google Sheets formula that simplifies running a Condorcet method election?
I occasionally create fictional elections for fun and experiment with different methods of doing them. This time, I did an election for the presidency of a country, and I planned to carry it out with a Condorcet method. For those who aren't familiar, a Condorcet method is any election system that declares the candidate who can beat all of their competitors, or more of the other candidates than anyone else, the winner. This winner is the Condorcet winner. I created a way to calculate who would be the Condorcet winner with a bunch of tables within my spreadsheet.
Here's an image to help explain things, the first of two. It contains the row and column values.
This first table contains several columns, corresponding to the election candidates and their supporters. Each candidate's supporters have distinct preferences for which candidate they would like to win. The candidate who is named in the top rows is the first preference of their voters. Beneath them are all the other candidates. At the bottom is the number of voters whose first preference is the candidate whose name is at the top of the column.



CONDORCET METHODS
Voters for Melian
Voters for Finwio
Voters for Kunlang
Voters for Lobbens
Voters for Grunxi
Voters for Dorekori
Voters for Tebulis
Voters for Edelän
Voters for Limbagge
Voters for Tanthani
Voters for Salmond




Preference 1
Melian
Finwio
Kunlang
Lobbens
Grunxi
Dorekori
Tebulis
Edelän
Limbagge
Tanthani
Salmond


Preference 2
Kunlang
Tebulis
Melian
Kunlang
Tanthani
Tebulis
Dorekori
Melian
Melian
Lobbens
Dorekori


Preference 3
Finwio
Salmond
Lobbens
Tanthani
Lobbens
Finwio
Finwio
Kunlang
Lobbens
Kunlang
Tebulis


Preference 4
Edelän
Melian
Tanthani
Edelän
Kunlang
Salmond
Salmond
Limbagge
Kunlang
Melian
Melian


Preference 5
Limbagge
Edelän
Edelän
Melian
Melian
Limbagge
Melian
Tanthani
Edelän
Limbagge
Edelän


Preference 6
Lobbens
Kunlang
Limbagge
Limbagge
Limbagge
Melian
Tanthani
Lobbens
Tanthani
Tebulis
Finwio


Preference 7
Tanthani
Lobbens
Grunxi
Salmond
Edelän
Lobbens
Edelän
Salmond
Finwio
Edelän
Kunlang


Preference 8
Tebulis
Dorekori
Finwio
Grunxi
Finwio
Tanthani
Limbagge
Finwio
Salmond
Salmond
Tanthani


Preference 9
Salmond
Tanthani
Salmond
Finwio
Salmond
Edelän
Lobbens
Tebulis
Tebulis
Grunxi
Limbagge


Preference 10
Grunxi
Grunxi
Tebulis
Tebulis
Tebulis
Kunlang
Kunlang
Grunxi
Dorekori
Finwio
Lobbens


Preference 11
Dorekori
Limbagge
Dorekori
Dorekori
Dorekori
Grunxi
Grunxi
Dorekori
Grunxi
Dorekori
Grunxi


Original apportionment
146904
11791
39631
34314
60865
151989
203284
12238
57745
23282
353



Beneath that is another table. It contains all of the votes each candidate would get, based on the preferences in the first table, if they were pitted against each other in a series of one-on-one contests. The candidate whose name is listed in every column at the top of the spreadsheet is pitted against the candidates whose names are in the rows on the left. In each cell within each column in the imaged table, the votes for the candidate listed at the top of the column are counted up. There's a conditional formatting rule that turns the cell blue if the candidate has a majority of votes. Beneath all the candidates are a set of four rows. The first row lists how many times they got a majority of votes, the second lists the average number of votes they received, and the last one ranks them in descending order, with the candidate with the most victories getting the rank of 1. Where a candidate would be pitted against themself, that cell is represented with "Candidate vs self" in markdown.



CANDIDATE MATCHUPS (ORIGINAL)
Melian
Finwio
Kunlang
Lobbens
Grunxi
Dorekori
Tebulis
Edelän
Limbagge
Tanthani
Salmond
Win count against candidate




vs Melian
Candidate vs self
367064
158093
118462
60866
355626
367417
46552
244049
118462
198447
0


vs Finwio
375332
Candidate vs self
374979
228076
158093
378908
378908
228429
228076
228076
70187
4


vs Kunlang
584303
367417
Candidate vs self
531480
60866
367417
367417
379655
413018
473735
367417
5


vs Lobbens
623934
514320
210916
Candidate vs self
60866
367417
367417
374569
572512
311813
367417
4


vs Grunxi
681530
584303
681530
681530
Candidate vs self
425162
607584
681530
669739
681530
641899
10


vs Dorekori
386770
363488
374979
374979
317234
Candidate vs self
590054
386770
374979
374979
363841
7


vs Tebulis
374979
363488
374979
374979
134812
152342
Candidate vs self
351697
374979
374979
165516
5


vs Edelän
695844
513967
362741
367827
60866
355626
390699
Candidate vs self
497166
513366
367417
5


vs Limbagge
498347
514320
329378
169884
72657
367417
367417
245230
Candidate vs self
373521
367417
3


vs Tanthani
623934
514320
268661
430583
60866
367417
367417
229030
368875
Candidate vs self
367417
3


vs Salmond
543949
672209
374979
374979
100497
378555
576880
374979
374979
374979
Candidate vs self
9


WIN COUNT
10
6
5
6
0
3
5
5
7
7
1



MAX VOTES
695844
672209
681530
681530
317234
425162
607584
681530
669739
681530
641899



AVG VOTES
538892.2
477489.6
351123.5
365277.9
108762.3
351588.7
438121
329844.1
411837.2
382544
327697.5



RANK
1
4
6
4
11
9
6
6
2
2
10




The votes are tallied up as follows: every candidate receives the votes of each group of voters who prefer them over their opponent, according to the preferences in the first table. Originally, I did this manually. I went through each time and summed up the number of votes. It got very exhausting, taking about two hours to carry out. And this was for only one situation where the votes fell in a certain way! I did it manually once again with slightly different vote counts, which took a few more hours. I started to think of writing a formula that could handle it all for me.
I poked at several things under query(), lookup(), and vlookup(), none of which worked. I learned that none of them supported looking for matches in multiple cells across multiple rows and columns, or if they did, it was beyond my power to learn whether or not they did so tonight. Eventually, I got what I think might be the start of a workable formula. If, unfortunately, a very long one.
I started off by trying to change the value of cell B110 from a manual summation of the value I was looking for (the sum of all voters who prefer the candidate named in cells B2 and B95 over the candidate named in cell A110) to a formulaic one. The start of the formula is below.
=sumif($B$95:$B$105,if(match(B$95,$B$95:$B$105,0)<match(regexextract($A110,"vs\s([A-z|ä]+)"),$B$95:$B$105,0)=true,B$95,0),B106:L106)
It produced the following table. The only change from the second markdown table is that the cell right next to "vs Finwio" now only has the votes from the voters whose first preference is Melian:



CANDIDATE MATCHUPS (ORIGINAL)
Melian
Finwio
Kunlang
Lobbens
Grunxi
Dorekori
Tebulis
Edelän
Limbagge
Tanthani
Salmond
Win count against candidate




vs Melian
Candidate vs self
367064
158093
118462
60866
355626
367417
46552
244049
118462
198447
0


vs Finwio
146904
Candidate vs self
374979
228076
158093
378908
378908
228429
228076
228076
70187
4


vs Kunlang
584303
367417
Candidate vs self
531480
60866
367417
367417
379655
413018
473735
367417
5


vs Lobbens
623934
514320
210916
Candidate vs self
60866
367417
367417
374569
572512
311813
367417
4


vs Grunxi
681530
584303
681530
681530
Candidate vs self
425162
607584
681530
669739
681530
641899
10


vs Dorekori
386770
363488
374979
374979
317234
Candidate vs self
590054
386770
374979
374979
363841
7


vs Tebulis
374979
363488
374979
374979
134812
152342
Candidate vs self
351697
374979
374979
165516
5


vs Edelän
695844
513967
362741
367827
60866
355626
390699
Candidate vs self
497166
513366
367417
5


vs Limbagge
498347
514320
329378
169884
72657
367417
367417
245230
Candidate vs self
373521
367417
3


vs Tanthani
623934
514320
268661
430583
60866
367417
367417
229030
368875
Candidate vs self
367417
3


vs Salmond
543949
672209
374979
374979
100497
378555
576880
374979
374979
374979
Candidate vs self
9


WIN COUNT
10
6
5
6
0
3
5
5
7
7
1



MAX VOTES
695844
672209
681530
681530
317234
425162
607584
681530
669739
681530
641899



AVG VOTES
538892.2
477489.6
351123.5
365277.9
108762.3
351588.7
438121
329844.1
411837.2
382544
327697.5



RANK
1
4
6
4
11
9
6
6
2
2
10




The match formulas return the position of the cell in question, proxying for the preference of the voters who support the candidate named at the top of the column. If the candidate's cell position is lower than that of their opponent, then the criterion for the sumif is the candidate's name. Otherwise, it returns 0.
This only applies to one column out of eleven, of course. I'd need to copy and modify this eleven times for each of the eleven columns, representing the voters for each of the other ten candidates. In the end, the formula would be a
sum(sumif(the formula above),sumif(the formula above, but for column C), sumif (the formula above, for column D)
...for each column from B to L.
So...what I want is to find out if there exists a Google Sheets formula that can:

find a way to put all of the columns and rows in the same array
find and compare the position of two strings in multiple rows
sum up all of the votes (here, the numbers in row 106) in each column where the string representing the candidate listed in the column has a lower row than their opponent
provides the summed-up value in one cell
performs the above in a more compact manner than summing up sumifs

And if so, I'd appreciate some help in building it. I can share a copy of the sheet I did all of the work on originally, if needed.
This is the sample Google Sheet I've made with the relevant data and my one-cell attempt at a formula change.

In the current state of the post it is quite hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. Please edit your post and try to give it more focus.

I have created a "system" of sorts, and have some discrepancies to your results. Would you please double check the following: 1) "Melian & Limbagge": allocation of results for "Lobbens" (34,315 votes). 2) "Melian & Salmond": allocation of votes in each pair; your figures "Melian"=543949 & "Salmond"=198447; my figures "Melian"=374979 & "Salmond"=367417; allocation difference = 168970.
